# how to convert list of images to Batches for tensorflow classification

Tags: python, list, numpy, tensorflow

I have a question about the input baches (if understand it correctly). ([i refer this for the classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification))

There is a `train_images.shape` of fashion dataset is `(60000, 28, 28)`. if understand it correctly, it is 60000 images with 28*28 shape. `train_labels` is `array([9, 0, 0, ..., 3, 0, 5], dtype=uint8)`

In my case, I have a list which has images in it. The size of the list is `2000` and each image have the shape of `250*250`. I convert my labels using `np.array(y_train)`.

problem is-: i cant not use my "train_images" in `model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=50)` because it is not in a shape model needs.

I think, I need to convert the list of data into `(2000,250,250)`.

can someone help me with how to do that? i directly convert into List to Numpy. which it did not work.

also suggest me what could be the change if i use `(2000,250,250)`.

i did like this, but i think it is not optimal way to do it

```
final_traing = np.array([])
temp=X_train[0]
for i in range(1,len(X_train)):
  data_final=np.concatenate([temp, X_train[i]], axis=0)
  temp=final_traing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each image really has the shape `(250*250)`, you can try something like this:

```
import numpy as np

samples = 3
image1 = np.random.random((250*250))
image2 = np.random.random((250*250))
image3 = np.random.random((250*250))
X_train = np.asarray([image1, image2, image3])
print(X_train.shape)
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (samples, 250, 250))
print(X_train.shape)
```

```
(3, 62500)
(3, 250, 250)
```